# How to write Javascript code that doesn't block the ui

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance

I'm working on a javascript application that performs 2 jobs.

The first job is more important and needs to run at 60fps. The other job is a "background" job that still needs to run but it's okay if it takes longer.

Normally the way I would do this is have the more important job's code in a RequestAnimationFrame loop, and put the background job on a web worker.

However the main job is already spawning 2 web workers, and I don't want to spawn a third for context switching and memory consumption reasons.

There is ~8 ms of processing time left over on the RequestAnimationFrame loop that I have to work with for the background job to run on, however it is a job that will take about 100 ms to complete.

**My question is** there a way to write a loop that will pause itself every time the ui is about to be blocked?

Basically run as much code as you can until the remaining 8ms of time are up for the frame, and then pause until there is free time again.

Comment: Two questions: 1. What's the problem with the third web worker? 2. Are the other two web workers really busy **all the time**? Or could they incorporate this background work?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The application already uses a lot of memory, and a third web worker would just add to that.  The other 2 web workers have a little bit of buffer I can play with, but it's not steady as it depends on the data they are processing. Sometimes they work up to the last ms, other times they are free for almost the entire frame, but it's hard to tell until they actually get the data they need to process

Comment: Ref: **My question is**: the answer is **No**; I've seen very successful, very large apps using 16 and 32 WebWorkers. Your concern may be unfounded.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Okay that's interesting, I always thought this would be a problem on mobile. However one question I still have is what if a device only has 2 processing cores? The third worker would take away power from the other 2, which sometimes would cause the main animation to be less performant. Is there a way to offset this?

Comment: @YAHsaves - Remember that your webapp isn't the only thing asking for those cores, so even at a main thread plus two workers, there's plenty of context switching happening as the cores handle those three threads plus OS threads plus background threads from other apps plus...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I understand that, if the os is doing other things that out of my control, but I at least want to control what I have control over.

Comment: @YAHsaves - way out on a limb here, and perhaps way off base, but this is starting to smell like a design problem rather than a problem to be solved in a JIT compiled language at run time.

Comment: @RandyCasburn How do you see it as a design problem? The 2 webworkers are solving a 3d webgl scene. The 3rd worker is solving some data based on that scene but it's not actually part of the frame. How else should I implement this?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put all the disclaimers in. I have no way of knowing, but you've clearly thought it through. By the way, 3d WebGL was the driver behind the multi-worker app mentioned above :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently experimental technology which [isn't well-supported yet](https://caniuse.com/#feat=requestidlecallback), but: There's [`requestIdleCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback), which:

> ...queues a function to be called during a browser's idle periods. This enables developers to perform background and low priority work on the main event loop, without impacting latency-critical events such as animation and input response. Functions are generally called in first-in-first-out order; however, callbacks which have a timeout specified may be called out-of-order if necessary in order to run them before the timeout elapses.

One of the key things about rIC is that it receives an [`IdleDeadline` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IdleDeadline) which

> ...lets you determine how much longer the user agent estimates it will remain idle and a property, `didTimeout`, which lets you determine if your callback is executing because its timeout duration expired.

So you could have your loop stop when the [`deadline.timeRemaining()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IdleDeadline/timeRemaining) returns a small enough number of remaining milliseconds.

---

That said, I think I'd probably add the third worker and see what it looks like in aggressive testing before I tried other approaches. Yes, it's true that context-switching is costly and you don't want to overdo it. On the other hand, there's already plenty of other stuff going on on mobiles and architectures these days are quite fast at context switching. I can't speak to the memory demands of workers on mobiles (haven't measured them myself), but that's where I'd start.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - Yeah, reference opening phrase. :-)

Comment: Well this exactly what I was looking for! Too bad it's still experimental, but at least it gives me something to look into.

Comment: @YAHsaves - Yeah, it was a classic case of "Hey, wait, this sounds *awfully* familiar, I'm sure I ran across exactly this..." and then figuring out what I was remembering. :-) (Good question, btw.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `requestIdleCallback()` as the accepted answer does, but it is still experimental and I like coming up with stuff like this. You might even combine rIC with this answer to produce something more suited to your needs.

The first task is to split up your idle code into small runnable chunks so you can check how much time you have/spent between chunks.

One way is to create several functions in a queue that do the work needed, such as `unprocessed.forEach(x=>workQueue.push(idleFunc.bind(null,x)));}`, then have an executor that will at some point process the queue for a set amount of time.

If you have a loop that takes awhile to finish, you could use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and yield at the end of each loop, then run it inside recursive calls to `setTimeout()` with your own deadline or `requestIdleCallback()`.

You could also have a recursive function that when processed, would add itself back to the end of the queue, which could help when you want to give other work time to run or when creating a function per piece of work would be absurd (e.g., hundreds of array items bound to a function that together only take 1ms to process).

Anyway, here's something I whipped up out of curiosity.

```
class IdleWorkExecutor {
    constructor() {
        this.workQueue=[];
        this.running=null;
    }

    addWork(func) {
        this.workQueue.push(_=>func());
        this.start();
    }

    //
    addWorkPromise(func) {
        return new Promise(r=>{
            this.workQueue.push(_=>r(func()));
            this.start();
        });
        //DRY alternative with more overhead:
        //return new Promise(r=>this.addWork(_=>r(func())));
    }

    sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,ms));
    }

    //Only run the work loop when there is work to be done
    start() {
        if (this.running) {return this.running;}
        return this.running=(async _=>{
            //Create local reference to the queue and sleep for negligible performance gain...
            const {workQueue,sleep}=this;
            //Declare deadline as 0 to pause execution as soon as the loop is entered.
            let deadline=0;
            while (workQueue.length!==0) {
                if (performance.now()>deadline) {
                    await sleep(10);
                    deadline=performance.now()+1;
                }
                /*shift* off and execute a piece of work. *push and shift are used to
                  create a FIFO buffer, but a growable ring buffer would be better. This
                  was chosen over unshift and pop because expensive operations shouldn't
                  be performed outside the idle executor.*/
                workQueue.shift()(deadline);
            }
            this.running=false;
        })();
    }
}

//Trying out the class.
let executor=new IdleWorkExecutor();

executor.addWork(_=>console.log('Hello World!'));

executor.addWorkPromise(_=>1+1).then(ans=>{
    executor.addWork(_=>console.log('Answer: '+ans));
});

//A recursive busy loop function.
executor.addWork(function a(counter=20) {
    const deadline=performance.now()+0.2;
    let i=0;
    while (performance.now()<deadline) {i++}
    console.log(deadline,i);
    if (counter>0) {
        executor.addWork(a.bind(null,counter-1));
    }
});
```

If you can use `requestIdleCallback()` in your code, adding it to `IdleWorkExecutor` is pretty simple:

```
function rICPromise(opt) {
    return new Promise(r=>{
        requestIdleCallback(r,opt);
    });
}

if (!deadline||deadline.timeRemaining()>0) {
    deadline=await rICPromise({timeout:5000});
}
```